# Django admin sortable won't save

Tags: django, django-admin

I have this in models.py:

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    discussion = models.ForeignKey(Discussion, blank=True, null=True)
    upload = ThumbnailerField(upload_to='upload/%s/%s' % (datetime.datetime.now().year, datetime.datetime.now().month ))
    mimetype = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="application/octet-stream")
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
```

and this in admin.py:

```
class UploadInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Upload
    extra = 0
    sortable_field_name = 'order'
```

and I register the UploadInline like this:

```
class DiscussionAdmin(ContentAdmin):
    inlines = [
        UploadInline
    ]
```

It displays okay and I can add new uploads, but the ordering doesn't work. It resets as soon as I press Save.

Any ideas what's happening here? I use similar ordering in other places in the app and it works normally.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out what was the problem. The functionality in question belongs to Grapelli. When I've had that figured out, it was a simple matter of reading the docs.

In order for it to work, I had to add this in the Upload class:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['order']
```

And that was it. Works okay.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had followed the guide, but then added `primary_key=True` to the ordering field, and I don't think it played nicely with that. Adding a new `order` field resolved the issue.